# Magento default zoom for product image is not working properly

Tags: product-images, magento2.2.3, zoom

I'm using **Magento 2.2.3**. The issue I'm facing is that the default zoom functionality is not working properly in the Product Image.

Here's the link to our development site:

http://37.152.57.114/min-bok-om-faglar

Please check the above product, when you double-click the product image, the zoom functionality is not working for some pages. For example, the zoom is working for the first page for the above-said product but the zoom is not working for other pages for the same product when you double click on the product image.

Could you please help me to resolve this issue?

Looking for your suggestion.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

**Update :**
Image zoom works for some products and doesn't for others is because your product images are not as much large to where zoomer functionality should be available :

For example :

above product zoom is working because your image size is 900 x 1200 :
http://37.152.57.114/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/189fe8db56a91dc68672618a725a226d/m/i/min-bok-om-f_glar-960x1200-page1.jpg

And for this product :
http://37.152.57.114/skrivstilsloggen

zoom is not working because image is not large enough where zoom functionality should be available.
http://37.152.57.114/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/189fe8db56a91dc68672618a725a226d/2/3/2304-majema-skrivstilsloggen-sidurval-420x600-page1_2.jpg

TIP : if you resize your browser screen you will see + - will appear as soon window ( height ) reduces in size.

Comment: Thanks for your information. But I don't want to use "Magnifier" for the zoom. In my case, the default zoom which is when we double click on the product image, the image is not zooming properly for some pages. I hope you got my point.

Comment: @Magentovsmarttec, i have updated the answer with my findings.

Comment: But if you check the third page on the below product, the zoom is not working when we double-click,  this is where I'm stuck :
http://37.152.57.114/min-bok-om-faglar